# Storing your jwt token in react or angular or vue

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, local-security-authority

Hi friends thank you for answering this question.

Where do you store  token jwt and what do you think is safer to keep token?

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#local-storage

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to store the token in localStorage.

See (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

If you using the token in a web application on a public or shared access machine, then the JWT token must include the expiration time (exp) claim, so that the potential for token re-use is minimized.

There is another alternative that is preferred in many commercial systems and that is to store the tokens as sessions on a secure data store. This method I have less experience in and is where it can be explored with third-party token authentication providers.